# CSS Styles won't work in Local xampp server

Tags: html, css, xampp, frontend, localserver

why doesn't CSS styles show up correctly on xampp server

Note: I have linked the stylesheet correctly. And some styles seem to apply. But some style doesn't work on Xampp

Comment: You sure it's related to xammp? maybe it's browser, change your browser or update it.

Comment: Maybe the issue is caching. Try a hard reload by pressing ctrl/cmd + F5

Comment: Please check console for errors

Answer (score 1):

You can use stylesheet versioning

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1.1">
</head>
```

If you use this even all modern browsers see that there is a new file. You can do the same for your javascript documents.

You can read more about this over here: https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another browser and if you see the CSS there, then the problem is the Chrome's cache. To clear them, go to

> chrome://settings/clearBrowserData

and clear the data

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and solved it by changing the name of the folder inside htdocs which contains the webpages. 
Hope it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please empty your browser cache and reload. Sometimes modern browsers do cache stylesheets and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The styles apply once you override the locally catched version: simply press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>r</kbd>

Comment: The keyboard shortcuts may be different depending on the OS. For example, I am using chrome and the shortcut is CTRL + Shift + Backspace

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but my problem with CSS files not linking was because I had put them another folder layer or 2 deep and had to add  .. before the file reference.

Was  /cssfile
Had to change to  ../cssfile